# Why doesn't ReadOnlyCollection<> include methods like FindAll(), FindFirst(), 

Tags: c#, collections, readonly-collection

Following the suggestions of FxCop and my personal inclination I've been encouraging the team I'm coaching to use ReadOnlyCollections as much possible. If only so that recipients of the lists can't modify their content. In their theory this is bread & butter. The problem is that the List<> interface is much richer exposing all sorts of useful methods. Why did they make that choice?

Do you just give up and return writable collections? Do you return readonly collections and then wrap them in the writable variety? Ahhhhh.

---

Update: 
Thanks I'm familiar with the Framework Design Guideline and thats why the team is using FxCop to enforce it. However this team is living with VS 2005 (I know, I know) and so telling them that LINQ/Extension methods would solve their problems just makes them sad.

They've learned that List.FindAll() and .FindFirst() provide greater clarity than writing a foreach loop. Now I'm pushing them to use ReadOnlyCollections they lose that clarity.

Maybe there is a deeper design problem that I'm not spotting.

-- Sorry the original post should have mentioned the VS2005 restriction. I've lived with for so long that I just don't notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 8.3.2 of the [.NET Framework Design Guidelines Second Edition](http://www.moserware.com/2008/12/private-life-of-public-api.html):

> **DO** use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, a subclass of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, or in rare cases `IEnumerable<T>` for properties or return values representing read-only collections.

We go with ReadOnlyCollections to express our intent of the collection returned.

The `List<T>` methods you speak of were added in .NET 2.0 for convenience. In C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5, you can get all those methods back on `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (or any `IEnumerable<T>`) using extension methods (and use LINQ operators as well), so I don't think there's any motivation for adding them natively to other types. The fact that they exist at all on List is just a historical note due to the presence of extension methods being available now but weren't in 2.0.

Comment: Sadly the team is stuck in the time warp of 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

First off, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>`.  With all of the extension methods in .NET 3.5 and LINQ, you have access to nearly all of the functionality from the original `List<T>` class in terms of querying, which is all you should do with a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` anyways.

That being said, your initial question leads me to make some suggestions...

Returning `List<T>` is bad design, so it shouldn't be a point of comparison.  `List<T>` should be used for implementation, but for the interface, `IList<T>` should be returned.  The [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) specifically state:

"**DO NOT** use `ArrayList` or `List<T>` in public APIs." (Page 251)

If you take that into consideration, there is absolutely no disadvantage to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` when compared to `List<T>`.  Both of these classes implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>`, which are the interfaces that should be returned anyways.

Comment: Sadly the team is stuck in the time warp of 2.0.

Comment: @Mark Levison: Even in 2.0, you should return IList<T>, not List<T>, so the comments still apply.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any insight as to why they weren't originally added.  But now that we have LINQ I certainly see no reason to add them in future versions of the language.  The methods you mentioned can easily be written in a LINQ query today.  These days I just use the LINQ queries for pretty much everything.  I actually more often get annoyed with `List<T>` having those methods because it conflicts with extension methods I write against `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Sadly the team is stuck in the time warp of 2.0.

Comment: @Mark, are you allowed to use VS2008 to compile C# 2.0 compatible code?  If so, you can just define these extension methods yourself

Comment: No the problem is that they don't have 2008 licenses yet. Apparently the plan to move 2008 has been on the books for a while. Nutss #!@&*#

Comment: No the problem is that they don't have 2008 licenses yet. Apparently the plan to move 2008 has been on the books for a while. Nutss #!@&*#

Answer (score 0):

I think Jeff's answer kinda contains the answer you need; instead of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, return a subclass of it... one that you implement yourself to include the methods that you'd like to use without upgrading to VS2008/LINQ.